# Issue while setting up a new Laravel application with Laragon

Tags: laragon

When I create a new Laravel project un l'Aragon, it creates the database but not the folder for the new project. In the terminal, it shows this message:

> The specified path was not found

Comment: Please check the path that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But which path are you talking about please ? The installation path ?

Comment: When I go to www folder, there is no folder created with the name of project I gave. But the database was created